# Error when typing arrows

Tags: math-mode, tikz-cd

I have recently installed Texmaker and Miktex on my new laptop, but I can't get my tikzdiagrams to work.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal{C}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}

\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}A\arrow[r,""]&B\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

This gives the following error: ! Missing \endcsname inserted.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `mathtools` include `amsmath`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dutch` languageis messing with the `"`. Adding

```
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
```

solves this.